# Поиск пути по графу с ограничением количества шагов

Tags: алгоритм, поиск-пути

Есть граф. 
Нужно найти кратчайший путь между двумя вершинами. Но! Есть ограничение по **минимально** пройденному расстоянию. При этом для достижения этого условия возможно повторное посещение вершин, в том числе циклическое.
Между вершинами возможен как переход к "дочерним", так и к "родительским" - в произвольном направлении. На вершину может ссылаться сколько угодно других вершин, но вершина ссылается только на две вершины, либо ни на одну.

Например, `A->C` с ограничением в минимум 4 шага: `A B A B C` или `A B C B C`
Другой пример, `A->B` с ограничением в 5 шагов: `A B C D E D C B` (пример глупый, знаю, проще было чередовать AB, но для наглядности хотелки).

Собсно, классический Дейкстра не подходит из-за возможности повторного посещения.
А* вообще не соображу как применить. Да и остальные "классические" алгоритмы.

В принципе можно было бы использовать классический Дейкстра, рекурсивно с вычитанием пройденного расстояния из минимально возможного...

Но может быть есть какие-нибудь еще идеи? Язык, по сути, не важен, вопрос не о языке. Если для вероятности использования как-то структуры из коробки - задача для Javascript/TypeScript. Спасибо!

Comment: чем поиск в ширину не подходит?

Comment: ну или да, Дейкстра. Только не запоминайте по каким вершинам уже прошли и все дела.

Comment: тем, что собственно возможно (я бы даже сказал - приветствуется) повторный проход вершины. ни Дейкстра, ни в ширину этого не обеспечивают, и без костылей находят только кратчайший.

Comment: если у Дейкстры не запоминать пройденные вершины - она рано или поздно уйдет в переполнение стека.

Comment: ну измените алгоритм, просто не запоминайте вершины, по которым уже прошли. Какие проблемы с этим?

Comment: он уйдет в переполнение только если цель недостижима

Comment: ну и необязательно Дейкстру вызывать рекурсивно, используйте итеративную реализацию. Плюс если после очередного шага ни одна новая вершина не была пройдена - то цель недостижима

Comment: ищите кратчайший. В дереве всё равно путь один по большому счёту. Потом туда-сюда ходите в соседнюю и ладно) Если вдруг это граф а не дерево, то разделите вершину на 2 виртуальные (чётную и нечётную).

Comment: Да, это граф. С заголовком накосячил, но первое же предложение поясняет.